# Changing the log level

Tags: python, django, logging, python-2.7, django-models

I have set the log level as `WARN` in `platform_settings.py` and `loggings.py` file.

I have also changed the initial value to `WARN` in `forms.py` with `(self.fields['log_level'].initial='WARN')`.

Now, if I change the value from `WARN` to `INFO` or `CRITICAL`, I would like it to reflect in the UI without setting `[log_level.initial]` every time. How would I make the changes to do this?

`platform_settings.py`

```
for l in loggers:
    logger = logging.getLogger(l)
    logger.setLevel(level)
```

`logging.py`

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': True,

  'formatters': {
     'cloudos_format': {
        'format': '%(filename)s [(process)d-%(thread)d-%(clientip)s]%(module)s.%(funcName)s:%(message)s'
            },
   },

   'handlers': {
     'null': {
      'level': 'WARN',
      'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
     },
```

`forms.py`

```
choices = [ ('WARN', 'Warning'),
            ('ERROR', 'Error'),
            ('CRITICAL', 'Critical'),
            ('INFO', 'Info'),
            ('DEBUG', 'Debug') ]
self.fields['log_level'].choices = choices
# self.fields['log_level'].initial='WARN'

cache_val = cloudos_cache.get('all_users', 'log_level')
if cache_val:
   self.fields['log_level'].initial = cache_val
else:
   logger = logging.getLogger('skyline')
   Lev=logging.getLevelName(level)
   logger.setLevel(Lev)
```